# Navigation in a UItoolbar in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

I have something like a toolbar includes some buttons. user can move to left and right as you see. I know how to set the button in toolbar, but I don't know how can I fix this kind of navigation on the toolbar. Is it possible in the toolbar?

If yes, how?

if no, do you know any control in iOS that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth browsing through [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls). They really have a lot of excellent pre-made custom controls for iOS and the Mac.

Personally, I would just create my own custom UIScrollView subclass which contains some UIButtons. Then set the scrollview to `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES` after setting a correct content size.

Apple has an excellent guide on using scrollviews with paging here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html