# navigation in actionbar sherlock

Tags: java, android

I would like to implement the navigation with options like left and right button that are displayed in following URL. I found the Tab Option for android is possible via Action Bar and Tab Host Control. But I can not find the option with those two button actions.

[Navigation in a UItoolbar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503932/navigation-in-a-uitoolbar-in-ios)

I also tried this by using Linear Layout and horizontal Scrollview  concepts but the UI are not comfort as i wish . So If you find Anything Kindly do the needful.

Comment: you not mean SlideNavigation ?

Comment: Try using fragments.

The bottom bar fragment will contain buttons for navigation. And clicking on any option in those will result in change of layout of the Detail fragment that is above the bottom bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want useing SlideNavigation use this library as i used this in my app for create Navigation [SlideNavigaiton](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation)

and if you want Navigation Ontab you can use scrollable tab as you can see in sherlock actionbar sample and on other way you can Hide actionBar and create custom layout with scrollable contetn for your aim

 hope to be usefull :)